# Ksoap2 Android IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am using Ksoap2 to consume my webservices, on some devices i am getting this exception, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made.

I am trying to resolve it from two days but without any key to resolve it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:496)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:258)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.setRequestProperty(ServiceConnectionSE.java:101)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:156)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
at mypkg.webservice.SoapRequest.getResponse(SoapRequest.java:66)
at mypkg.webservice.SoapObjectService.call(SoapObjectService.java:45)
at mypkg.webservice.ServiceCall.call(ServiceCall.java:29)
at mypkg.loadContentFromService(ContentManager.java:207)
at mypkg.loadContentFromCache(ContentManager.java:177)
at mypkg.refreshContent(ContentManager.java:125)
at mypkg.refresh(MyClass.java:93)
at mypkg.syncAll(MyClass2.java:148)
```

And here is how i am using Ksoap,

```
   String soapAction = SERVICE_NAMESPACE + methodName;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SERVICE_NAMESPACE, methodName);
    if (properties != null)
        for (PropertyInfo pro : properties) {
            request.addProperty(pro);
        }

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(serviceURL, 30000);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = false;
    androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
return envelope.getResponse();
```

Any one can help with this?

Regards

Comment: I was getting same exception when i passed bad value to PropertyInfo i added to request. Could you show more information about properties you are putting into PropertyInfo?

Comment: i am adding normal service method params, like user id, user name, password etc