# Exception; Cannot set request property after connection is made; occurs on Android lollipop HTC M8

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-5.0-lollipop, android-ksoap2

I am calling a `Java Web Service` from an `Android`application using `Soap`requests. There is a certain method to be called through the app which works fine in `Android` versions up to `Kit Kat` in almost all the devices and in Samsung `Lollipop` devices too, but doesn't work on HTC M8 Lollipop updated device.
Following is my code.

```
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE("URL");
SoapObject so = new SoapObject("Namespace", "Method");
try {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope se = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    so.addProperty("input1", data);
    data = se.getResponse().toString();//This is where Exception occurs

}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

An `Exception` occurs when trying to get the response as indicated by the comment and the exact `Exception` is as follows.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:496)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:258)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.setRequestProperty(ServiceConnectionSE.java:101)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:156)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
```

I have been searching for this but could not find a proper answer or a workaround even.
I looked for
[Ksoap2 Android IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979672/ksoap2-android-illegalstateexception) 
and 
[setRequestProperty method giving java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set method after connection is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726195/setresponsecode-method-giving-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-method)

I have no idea why it is occured in HTC M8 `Lollipop` device but not in Samsung `Lollipop` devices.
Any suggestions or workarounds are much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might explain the issue. Look for the 4<sup>th</sup> particle in the thread. 
https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=205&can=1&start=200

It says,

> Ahh.. they might have added ksoap2 android in their firmware.. that
>   would explain it. Not sure that is anything you can do beyond shading
>   the whole ksoap2-android package you use and any dependencies into
>   your own namespace. A rather huge undertaking..

You can do two possible things to identify exactly if this is the issue.

1. Try renaming the `ksoap2` class name
2. Directly access `ksoap2` class with preceding the `package` name.